# Node.js joi - .number() fails to pas 0

Tags: node.js, joi

I have this joi schema using .number() for a body parameter 'public'

```
contactSchema: Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
    public: Joi.number().required()
}),
```

If I allow the paremeter to be 0 in some instance ...

```
if(req.session.sessionEmail){
    var isPublic = 0;
  } else {
    var isPublic = 1;
  }
```

... joi says its invalid.

If I don't pass a 0 ... all is good?

```
if(req.session.sessionEmail){
    var isPublic = 2;
  } else {
    var isPublic = 1;
  }
```

Why does it fail in case of 0?

https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#number---inherits-from-any

Comment: Never used Joi before, but based on the coerciveness of `0` in JS, it might be getting mixed up and seeing this as "falsey". From the docs there's a [min](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#numberminlimit) function, would `Joi.number().min(0)` maybe work? Although, unless I am misunderstanding what `isPublic` represents....wouldn't [boolean()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#boolean---inherits-from-any) be more appropriate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one: `Joi.number().integer()`

```
contactSchema: Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
    public: Joi.number().integer().required()
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

```
userId: joi.number().integer().min(1).required()
```